# random string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that will generate a random string of text when i run it.

I have got far but im having a problem with formatting.

Here is the code im using

```
import random    
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

min = 5
max = 15

name = random.sample(alphabet,random.randint(min,max))

print name
```

And when ever i end up with this

```
['i', 'c', 'x', 'n', 'y', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'h', 'p', 'w', 'o']
```

I am trying to format so it is one line of string so for example

```
['i', 'c', 'x', 'n', 'y', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'h', 'p', 'w', 'o'] = icxnybgrhpwo
```

Comment: Note that the `sample` function always chooses a set of unique letters, so you'll run into a problem if `max` is greater than 26 (ValueError: sample larger than population).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.join) it:

```
>>> name = ['i', 'c', 'x', 'n', 'y', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'h', 'p', 'w', 'o']
>>> ''.join(name)
'icxnybgrhpwo'
```

Comment: Awesome it worked i put the variable in there i came up with ''.join(name)

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
import random

def create_random(length=8):
    """ Create a random string of {length} length """
    chars = string.letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.Random().sample(chars, length))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to print an alphabet :

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

([source](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase))